# Change Crystal Reports object visibility programmatically

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# 2010 application which contains reports created with Crystal Reports for VS2010.

For one of the reports, there is the option to print the report or e-mail it to someone [export and send via SMTP].

I want the watermark to be shown when viewing the report and also when e-mailing it. I do not want it to be shown when it is printed since it will be printed on watermarked page.

I would like to know how I can change the watermark visibility in the form which contains the crystalReportViewer programmatically [not on runtime], so that when printing, it doesn't print the watermark too.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a boolean parameter (`{?Show Watermark}`)
- Add `Not({?Show Watermark})` to the conditional formula of the image or the section that contains the image
- Set the value of the parameter programatically.