# Change visibility of object When Report Has No Data

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a beginner in Crystal Report. I am using `CR7`.

There are around 20 modules which has about 1000 reports.
In organization at many point of time there is no data present in DB for any particular report. In that case it don't show anything in report.
Actually I wanted to display a Text Object showing **"No Data to Display"**.

I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930894/change-crystal-reports-object-visibility-programatically) Post, but I can't apply this method since It is using parameter which is passed through application. If I go with that solution It will increase the *Cost* for organization. I don't want that.

**Question:**

I wanted to change visibility of a object on the basis of number of recods which Report Query gets. Means If `0` recod count then `visible = true`.
If solution present then please share...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Crystal Reports: Display a Message When Report Has No Data](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2007/08/28/crystal-reports-display-a-message-when-report-has-no-data/)